# Azure resources using storage

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azureportal

In Azure portal, how do I see dependencies between different resources. I specifically want to see which resources are using the storage that I want to delete.

Comment: What resources are involved? Upon inspection of the storage containers you might be able to see what uses it. There might be some logs for example. By the way, to avoid this in the future use something like tags or put all parts of a solution in a dedicated resource group.

Answer (score 1):

You can use application insights application map to do this:

[image: Application Insights Application Map]

You can also turn on logging for storage accounts:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/manage-storage-analytics-logs?tabs=azure-portal

Comment: What’s the reason for the down vote? I use application insights for this regularly to see a visual representation of connections in applications.

Comment: And where is the option for Application Insights Application Map. I dont see it under storage

Comment: As far as I’m aware you can’t add a storage account directly to a specific application insights instance. To see an application map like above you need to add the other main elements of your application to an app insights insurance and azure will add in access to storage accounts, external API calls, etc.

Comment: I didn't vote,  but: This works if you have a workload that supports adding AI like a web app or function but only then. If you have a logic app,an iot solution or something similar it won't work.

Comment: Yes that’s true for the application map, more info is required on the question really as you’ve said above.

Comment: In our dev environment, we try lots of different solutions. So we can have Logic Apps, Function Apps, messaging solutions, service bus, Web apps etc. Once done we remove those but the underlying storage stays. Now we are not sure which ones to keep and which ones to delete. Going to other resources and figuring this out is going to be cumbersome. I am looking for some way to figure this out easily. Do you think resource graph query would help

Comment: So it sounds like organising your testing of services into specific resource groups would help in that case. Then you can delete the entire resource group when done. As Peter says tags may also help if your setup is more complex or you want to organise things into multiple resource groups during testing.